# Intersect tables with different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So basically I have two tables

**posts** (simple articles)

[image]

**posts_wall** (articles posted on that user wall)

[image]

Now I want to combine them somehow, and order them by the date they was created/updated, and if the post don't have upload,upload_id column be NULL, even from posts_wall table, so I got 2 objectives

1. Intersect the 2 tables.
2. Order them by date.

And also:

What column I should add for `timeline`? one like `2012-01-01` or `13405848858` seconds since 1970 ?

For what I know I must `INTERSECT` them, but

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM posts_wall
```

Gives me syntax error.

The reason I'm doing this is that I want to see posts that `USER1` has rights t see them, and the posts posted by any user on `USER1` wall.

Also another column named `article_or_wall_article` to know if this is an article or a post on somebody wall, would be great, I want a good elegant approach

Answer (score 0):

You want an INNER JOIN based on a field...? It is not clear from your question what field do you want to join on.

For timestamps, there are pro and con in both cases - timestamps require conversion but allow easier comparison of dates.

In MySQL, you have to specify which fields come from which table and how to correlate them. I don't really see a meaningful JOIN between "posts" and "posts_wall".

If you want BOTH sets of records, then you need a UNION between the two tables:

```
select field1, field2, field3 from posts
UNION field1, field2, field3 from posts_wall
```

If you don't have a field in one of the tables, choose a suitable value and datatype and replace the missing field:

```
...UNION field1, field2, "NOTHING!" as field3 from posts_wall
```

Comment: on a users wall, like in fb i have posts by that user and posts by other, only the difference is that you cannot see what somebody that is not friend posted, and the post format are different, POSTS have posted_by(user id) posted_in(group_id) and WALL_POSTS have senede_by(user_id) sended_to(user_id), understand?

Answer (score 0):

@Row Minds for intersection of two tables  you must have an equal number of columns. What i understand from your question below is query that might help for you

```
Select * 
from
(
SELECT Posted_by as UserID,title, content, PostedDate
FROM posts
INTERSECT
SELECT  Sended_by as UserID,title, content,PostedWallDate as PostedDate 
FROM posts_wall
)A
Order by PostedDate desc
```